# dpkg error: contains ununderstood data member

Tags: makefile, jailbreak, dpkg, theos

I'm trying to install a jailbreak tweak using `make package install` but I'm receiving this error from dpkg:

```
dpkg-deb: file `/tmp/_theos_install.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /tmp/_theos_install.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/_theos_install.deb
make: *** [internal-install] Error 1
```

So as far as I can tell it isn't able to understand the .xz extension, but I'm not sure why that file is being created. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found out how to fix it. In `$THEOS/makefiles/package/deb.mk` replace this line:

```
 $(ECHO_NOTHING)COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 $(FAKEROOT) -r dpkg-deb -b "$(THEOS_STAGING_DIR)" "$(_THEOS_DEB_PACKAGE_FILENAME)" $(STDERR_NULL_REDIRECT)$(ECHO_END)
```

with this line:

```
$(ECHO_NOTHING)COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 $(FAKEROOT) -r dpkg-deb -Zgzip -b "$(THEOS_STAGING_DIR)" "$(_THEOS_DEB_PACKAGE_FILENAME)" $(STDERR_NULL_REDIRECT)$(ECHO_END)
```

Comment: i am facing the same issue and using ubuntu but can not locate `deb.mk` file.

Comment: if i have to come look at this... one more time... I am going to scream!

Comment: Using -Zlzma is recommended by other tweak developers.

Comment: This causes me another error: Could not find "./com.mytest.tweak2_0.0.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb" to install. Aborting. Any ideas?

Comment: finally, found it!

Answer (score 6):

The `.deb` file is created because you told Theos build system to do that. The `package install` rule of the Makefile is creating the Debian package using `xz` compression. Now, this kind of compression is supported by versions of `dpkg` equal or higher than 1.15.6.

So, in order to solve your problem, you should update `dpkg` to a newer version or install Theos without packaging support. Probably a simple `make install` will do it.

In case that updating `dpkg` isn't possible and you don't want to install the program without package management support, the other (more painful) method is to change the algorithm in which the package is compressed. [Here](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/17/how-to-create-debian-packages-with-alternative-compression-methods/) you have good information about how to do this.

Comment: How do I change the package install rule?

Comment: Thought I don't recommend you, if you want to go that way you can find what the rule does in the `Makefile` file.

Comment: I don't think I can update dpkg because I already have the newest version for ios. What do you suggest then?

Comment: I lack information about what you want to do, but if I were you I would first try to install the tool without package management support (probably with `make install`, as I said in my answer). If that weren't possible, I would try to change the compression method. I've updating my answer with more information about this.

Comment: Theos isn't installed. I just cloned the repo. Using make install instead of make package install causes the same error

Comment: Using -Zlzma is recommended by other tweak developers.

Comment: I think I already have the latest. Do I? 
RoverMR-2:tweak2 rover$ brew upgrade dpkg
Error: dpkg-1.17.21 already installed

Comment: `Now, this kind of compression is supported by versions of dpkg equal or higher than 1.15.6.` I've manually installed the version `1.16.0` and the problem still persisted!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was building a package on Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to install that package on Debian 7 (airgapped).  I had to change the line in the `Makefile` that read:

```
dpkg --build $(DESTDIR)
```

..to:

```
dpkg-deb --build -Zgzip $(DESTDIR)
```

Thanks Connor!

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you can try is to unpack the .deb that you where trying to install and repack with no XZ compression.

1. Unpack:

   ```
   mkdir package/ && dpkg -x package.deb package/
   ```
2. Pack:

   ```
   dpkg-deb --build -Zgzip package/
   ```

You can then rename the resulting package with:

```
dpkg-name -o package.deb
```

Or simply name the `package` dir with the name of your package.

**Important:** In order to perform this, you need to install `dpkg-dev` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dpkg-dev
```